# How to create a custom timing function?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, timing, uiviewanimationtransition

I am busy with a custom animated transition between UIViewControllers and I like the the UIView to jump and then fill up the space similar to the following screenshot:

[image]

Now there isn't an "Option" I could create such an effect. Now I could create a keyframe animation with one key at the top and one in the center but that wouldn't feel really natural, it would feel robotic.

How would one approach this?

**SOURCE (SO FAR)**

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext
{
    UIViewController    *fromVC    = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController    *toVC      = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView              *container = [transitionContext containerView];

    if ([fromVC isEqual:self])
    {
        [_activeCardView.superview bringSubviewToFront:_activeCardView];

        [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic
                                  animations:^{
                                      [_activeCardView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, toVC.view.bounds.size.width, toVC.view.bounds.size.height)];
                                  }
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                      [container addSubview:toVC.view];
                                      [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                                  }];
    }
    else
    {
        [container addSubview:toVC.view];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext]
                         animations:^{
                             [_activeCardView setFrame:_basicCardFrame];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
                         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a smooth 'jump' animation you could just chain two animations with 'EaseInOut' curves.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:<DURATION>/2 delay:<DELAY> options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void) {
        //move view up
    }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:<DURATION>/2 delay:<DELAY> options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^(void) {
            //move view down
        }completion:NULL];
    }];
```

Comment: That might work, Make the animation ease out and ease in might give the illusion of a curved acceleration. I am going to try it.